# wait for javascript thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, google-maps-api-3

does anyone know how to wait for an thread in javascript?

```
var resultList = new Array();

function query(){
    //more stuff
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback); //<-- this is the thread 

    console.log(resultList);        //<-- still empty array

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(resultList);    //<-- array filled (after hardcoded timeout)
    }, 1000);

}

function callback(results, status) {
    //...   
    resultList.push(resultObject);
}
```

do to the logic of the program, the handling with the resultList is not possible inside the callback function. It need to be in the "parent" (the query function). So in there i somehow need to wait for the thread (and so for the array to be filled) befor i can continiue and handel the result.

So my question. Is ther any .join() method like in java? or waitpid() like in Unix? or whats the best practice to wait for the finished task?

regards

Comment: There are no threads in javascript. The above code does not do what you think it does. `callback` is called on the same thread.

Comment: Put `console.log(resultList)` into your callback?

Comment: Instead of var resultList = new Array(); you should write var resultList = []; You can use google to learn why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is all executed in the same thread. It's a **blocking** thread that will stop the browser from updating the DOM until it returns to the browser.

This is why Javascript files should be included at the bottom of HTML pages.

The problem above is that `service.nearbySearch` is performing an AJAX or REST request to a server, and the response is asynchronous (will happen later).

You need to move your logic for handling the response to the callback.

```
var resultList = new Array();

function query(){
    service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
        callback(results, status);
        console.log(resultList);
    });
}

function callback(results, status) {
    //...   
    resultList.push(resultObject);
}
```